# Not able to add new intent in LUIS with ":"

Tags: azure-language-understanding

My whole application has intents with name having ":" .But now when i am trying to add new intent,its giving me error "BadArgument: Intent and entity name cannot contain the character ":" or "$" "

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, these special characters should not be used in intent names because they are reserved for other uses. An example of how the colon is used is in [entity roles in patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-model-intent-pattern). My recommendation is to rename your intents. I also recommend storing the intent names in your application as constant string resources so that the values can be easily changed.